# Azure NetX Duo: where can I find a driver compatible with my Ethernet PHY ADIN1200?

Tags: stm32, c, ethernet, stm32cubemx, rtos

### Context of my question

I am trying to use **Azure NetX Duo** with a micro STM32F4. I'm using the following tools:

- STM32CubeMX version 6.7.0
- In the STM32CubeMX I have installed the Package STM32F4 version 1.27.1
- To use ThreadX I have added to CubeMX the software pack X-CUBE-AZRTOS-F4 version 1.1.0

### Problem explanation

When I use STM32CubeMX to add **NetX Duo** by the Software Pack `STMicroelectronics.X-CUBE-AZRTOS-F4` I have to select the `Network Interface`. The only 2 possible choices are:

- LAN8742_Phy_Interface
- Custom_Phy_Interface

So I have selected `LAN8742_Phy_Interface`. At this choice STM32CumeMX associates the Ethernet Driver lan8742.c ([lan8742 code](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-lan8742/blob/main/lan8742.c)).

After compilation, and after I have downloaded on the Flash of STM32F4, the application starts and it initializes the Network Interface by the function:

```
int32_t LAN8742_Init(lan8742_Object_t *pObj);
```

During the execution of the function, it is executed the following for loop:

```
/* for later check */
pObj->DevAddr = LAN8742_MAX_DEV_ADDR + 1;
   
/* Get the device address from special mode register */  
for(addr = 0; addr <= LAN8742_MAX_DEV_ADDR; addr ++) {
    # -------------> the following instruction read the LAN8742_SMR register
    if(pObj->IO.ReadReg(addr, LAN8742_SMR, &regvalue) < 0) { 
        status = LAN8742_STATUS_READ_ERROR;
        /* Can't read from this device address continue with next address */
         continue;
    }
     
    if((regvalue & LAN8742_SMR_PHY_ADDR) == addr) {
        pObj->DevAddr = addr;
        status = LAN8742_STATUS_OK;
        break;
    }
}
```

Inside the loop there is the instruction: `if(pObj->IO.ReadReg(addr, LAN8742_SMR, &regvalue) < 0) { ... }` which reads the *special* register at address `LAN8742_SMR` where the constant `LAN8742_SMR` is defined in the file lan8742.h ([code of lan8742.h](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32-lan8742/blob/main/lan8742.h)) as below:

```
#define LAN8742_SMR      ((uint16_t)0x0012U)
```

The problem is that every times is executed the previous read function **on my board** its return value is `0x0000FFFF`.
In my board is present the **Ethernet PHY ADIN1200**. I'm pretty sure that the error in the read function means that *the driver LAN8742 is not compatible with my PHY*.

### My question

Does someone know where can I find a driver compatible with my **Ethernet PHY ADIN1200** that can I use with NetX Duo?

Thanks